# Multivariate hypergeometric functions

Tags: symbolic, special-functions

Anybody knows of any Mathematica implementation of multivariate hypergeometric functions? It requires Jack polynomials, or at least Schur polynomials for the real case. In addition it requires partitions of integers and generalized Pochhammer symbol.

If it helps, I can provide the Maple code for it. The problem is, there is a glitch in the Maple code. It does not perform symbolic calculations as promised. The Maple package is called MOPS
https://sites.math.washington.edu/~dumitriu/mopspage.html
I managed to make the package work, but not the function, through some tricks.

I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: None that I know of; I haven't even seen an implementation of the Schur or Jack polynomials. (I should really try finishing the routines I'm writing for those...)

Comment: Only [`AppellF1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppellF1.html) is available.

Comment: Here is the MATLAB implementation of the functions, highly optimized. That might help a good Mathematica implementation.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/00gomsrtc8ubwqs/hg.m?dl=0

Was unable to attach it here, but can send it to anyone. Ask me at ilia.toli@gmail.com

Comment: If somebody converts this MATLAB code to Mathematica code, I will cite them in my PhD thesis.